# Ruby on Rails 3 Routes Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

When clicked on the link below, it takes me to the show screen, instead of deleting the thing.

```
      <th><%= link_to 'Destroy', blog, :method => :delete %></th>
```

Controller

```
  def destroy
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
    @blog.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(root_path) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

Something must be wrong in my routes. can someone help me find the error?

```
PremSite::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :blogs

  resources :portfolios do
    member do
      get 'show_port'
    end
  end

  get "admin/index"

  resources :rosters

  #All the static service pages

  match "bloggers" => 'dashboard#bloggers'

  match "sitemap" => 'dashboard#sitemap'
  match "about" => 'dashboard#about'
  match "about_team" => 'dashboard#about_team'
  match "service" => 'dashboard#service'
  match "portfolio" => 'dashboard#portfolio', :as => 'view'
  match "contact" => 'dashboard#contact'
  match "blogger" => 'dashboard#blogger'
  match "admin" => 'admin#index'

  match "services/web_development" => 'services#web_development'
  match "services/design_brand" => 'services#design_brand'
  match "services/flash_solutions" => 'services#flash_solutions'
  match "services/ecommerce" => 'services#ecommerce'
  match "services/emarket" => 'services#emarket'
  match "services/applications" => 'services#applications'
  match "services/seo_solutions" => 'services#seo_solutions'
  match "services/google_adwords" => 'services#google_adwords'
  match "services/google_analytics" => 'services#google_analytics'
  match "services/website_evaluation" => 'services#website_evaluation'
  match "newsletter/join" => 'newsletter#join'

  root :to=> "dashboard#index"
end
```

Can someone explain where I went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, do you still need to use the respond_to block, or is this just a habit carried over from Rails 2.3.x? Check out http://bit.ly/13V5sC and http://bit.ly/d2Dwer for some info on the new respond_to/respond_with functionality.

Comment: Actually when I scaffold this Blog Model it came with it.

Comment: Kind of strange that the scaffold generator isn't using the newer code, but I would personally remove the respond_with block, as its a lot of unnecessary extra and just messing things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Rails Unobtrusive JavaScript (UJS) drivers for Prototype of jQuery?

In Rails 2.3 the :delete method would setup some JS in the link to send the request as a form post using the delete 'method' (via the _method param).

Now in Rails 3 the inline JS has been removed (thank goodness!) and you will notice that the link has a few new attributes, namely `data-method="delete"` and, if you are using the confirm option, `data-confirm="Your confirmation message"`.

The Rails UJS driver, when the page is loaded, looks for any links etc with these attributes and attaches events to them, which then does the same as what the inline javascript would have done.

If you are using Prototype you can find the UJS file at http://github.com/rails/prototype-ujs, and jQuery at http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs - just make sure this file is loaded *after* the JS framework, and *before* your application.js file.

Comment: Thank you, you steered me in the right direction. I was missing   <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %> inside of my admin layout.